# Parent-children relationship from two children of one different key

Tags: javascript, json

I am quite new to javascript and data structures and I have a JSON file and I would like to know if doing something like this is possible.

Raw JSON:

```
[{
    "name": "1.date.17-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.HOUSTON", "1.person.JOHN", "1.location.MIAMI", "1.person.BEN"]
},
{
    "name": "1.date.18-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.UBER", "1.person.JOHN"]
},
{
    "name": "1.person.JOHN",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.date.17-Nov-18", "1.date.18-Nov-18"]
},
{
    "name": "1.person.BEN",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.date.17-Nov-18"]
}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "name": "1.person.JOHN",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.date.17-Nov-18", "1.date.18-Nov-18", "1.person.BEN"]
},
{
    "name": "1.person.BEN",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.date.17-Nov-18", "1.person.JOHN"]
}
]
```

Basically, would it be possible to make them both parent and children of each other if they appeared together as a children from another parent? Like if two 1.person appeared from one key, they will now be parent-children and vice versa.

Hopefully I made my question clear.

Comment: there is a circular import with "1.person.JOHN" and "1.date.18-Nov-18"

Comment: What have you tried so far?